# is that possible to read before write using ReentrantReadWriteLock?

Tags: java, concurrency, reentrantlock

I am implementing a database which can read and write data. For concurrency issue, I need to implement lock. Normally, ReentrantReadWriteLock will let write execute before read. How Can I go reversely? Is  there a way that I can read before write thread executes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-read the [javadoc of ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html). It doesn't impose any order between reads and writes. All it does is allowing concurrent reads, but disallowing concurrent writes and writes concurrent with reads.

> This class has the following properties:
>
> Acquisition order
>
> - This class does not impose a reader or writer preference ordering for lock access. However, it does support an optional fairness policy.

Comment: the link you gave to me is ReentrantLock, it is slightly different from ReentrantReadWriteLock

Comment: Sorry, I took the wrong URL. Fixed now. The javadoc citation is from the javadoc of ReentrantReadWriteLock though, and my answer still stands. Read the javadoc.